# Removing dependencies on subclass-specific behavior

Tags: design, object-oriented, type-casting

I have a `Message` class which can contain multiple types of payloads (or sometimes no payload), each derived from a common `Payload` class. However, this becomes problematic because the `Message` class wants to know about the `Payload` subclasses for various reasons such as:

- Checking for `Message` equality

  ```
  if (message parts besides the payload are equal) {
      switch(type) {
          case Payload::Type::RESPONSE:
              return *static_cast<ResponsePayload*>(payload.get())
                  == *static_cast<ResponsePayload*>(o.payload.get());
              break;

          case Payload::Type::SETUP:
              return *static_cast<SetupPayload*>(payload.get())
                  == *static_cast<SetupPayload*>(o.payload.get());
              break;

          ...
      }
  }
  ```
- Deserializing (since the deserialization methods are static because the payloads are immutable)

  ```
  switch(type) {
      case Payload::Type::RESPONSE:
          load = ResponsePayload::fromJSON(payloadValue);
          break;

      case Payload::Type::SETUP:
          load = SetupPayload::fromJSON(payloadValue);
          break;

      ...

      case Payload::Type::START:
      case Payload::Type::STOP:
      case ...:
          break; // Load stays null

      default:
          THROW(Exception, "Error in program logic: we forgot to parse some payload");
  }
  ```
- Ensuring a `Payload` is attached to a `Message` while constructing it:

  ```
  switch(type) {
      case Payload::Type::RESPONSE:
      case Payload::Type::SETUP:
      case ...:
          ENFORCE(IOException, payload != nullptr, "For this message type, a payload is required.");
          break;

      case Payload::Type::START:
      case Payload::Type::STOP:
      case ...:
          ENFORCE(IOException, payload == nullptr, "For this message type, the payload should be null");
          break;

      default:
          THROW(Exception, "Error in program logic: we forgot to handle some payload");
  }
  ```

Alarm bells are going are going off in my head - this violates [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) like there's no tomorrow and obviously doesn't scale well since I have to add `case` statements every time I add a new payload. Is there a cleaner approach I could take?

Comment: Does it makes sense, in your design, for a basic payload object to know about the message object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alarm bells should be going off. But some top of my head initial suggestions (meaning I didn't take the time to come up with the best solution, just a much better one than you've got).

1 - Why is there a separate Message and Payload class, aren't they the same thing?

2 - Include the equality check in the subclasses where they take a payload instance as the parameter. Subclasses only know about their own type. If you pass a payload that isn't the right type then the type conversion will fail and you know they aren't equal.

3 - Create a Payload factory instead of creating all the various types in the base message class.

4 - Subclass the Message class if it requires parameters to be built properly.

Comment: Yes to all of this. OP should also have the payloads handle more logic.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I'm removing the `Payload` class and just subclassing `Message`, and things are already looking a lot cleaner.